# Can I boot with /home as readonly?

Tags: mount, home-directory, reboot, read-only

In connection to [Remotely recover file from rm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393060/remotely-recover-file-from-rm), I consider somehow setting up my system to intentionally boot with `/home` as readonly, and reboot.

**Is that possible?**

I am not sure about how to do it, and whether it will help me recovering the removed file, so any hints on that are also welcome.

Comment: Best thing you can do if you removed important files or the whole home directory (as happened to me) is to make a copy of the current disk status onto an external hard drive, e.g. with `dd` so you can't make further miskate or work that overwrites the still present file. The you can try a forensic instrument as foremost (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foremost_(software)) for the recovery of files. It is not goingo to be fast nor a simple challenge but you can try. Also take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101237/how-to-recover-files-i-deleted-now-by-running-rm

Comment: @opisthofulax - The problem is that I am not sure I can have physical access to the computer.

Comment: If /home is RO you cannot login using a GUI, but text terminal only.

Comment: @guiverc - Ok. With that caveat, would that work?
If so, what is the best way to configure `/home` for booting RO?